# How to write a javascript program that returns the subset of a string as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have seen examples but I still dont understand all of it. I know substring() is definately used but I need a step by step breakdown if possible. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What subset of the string ? (each letter?, separated by a delimiter?, multiple subsets of fixed size?)

Comment: for example "dog" returns ["d", "do", "dog", "o", "og" "g"])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can split the string using `String.split()` method and then you can create combinations with the elements by pushing in new array.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input string
let str = "dog";
// An empty array which will store the combinations.
let result = [];

/**
 * getCombination() method is used to get all the combinations of all the array elements passed as a parameter.
 */
function getCombination(inputArr) {
  // variable which will store the combination string.
  let temp = '';
  // Iterating input array to get elements one by one.
  inputArr.forEach((elem, index) => {
    // Pushing the element into result array.
    result.push(temp + elem);
    // To make the combination updating temp variable with the elem. 
    temp += elem + "";
  });
}
 
// Once combination done for one iteration, removing the first element from an array and then again calling getCombination() method to get the combination for next set of elements.
str.split('').forEach((elem, index) => {
    getCombination([...str.slice(index)]);
});

// Expected result
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Might be handy to add some comments how this works?

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to add comments please!

Comment: @AOmiyale Comment has been added. Please check and accept the answer if it works. So that it will help other developers as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I’m a new developer there are some terms I don’t understood some of the syntax in the function,  such as temp and elem… is elem meant to be element? Would it be possible to expand please? Thank you

Comment: `temp` is a temporary variable and `elem` is just a name of the array element. You can use any name.

Comment: Thank again, i know im being a pain but could you break down the function please (add comments)

Comment: the temp is that an empty string?

Comment: @AOmiyale Initially it is empty as we have to push a fresh combination everytime we call getCombination method. May I know why you unaccept the answer ?

Comment: I dont understand the function but ill research thanks! Accepted it

Comment: I added descriptive comments. Hope you will get the flow now.